# php mongo client update, overrides all document

Tags: php, mongodb

a simple mongo update is overiding my whole document.

my code:

```
function update($where, $data, $collection)
     $newdata = array('$set' => $data);

    if (isset($where['id'])) {
        $mongoID = new MongoID($where['id']);
        unset($where['id']);
        $where['_id'] = $mongoID;
    }

    $collection = $this->db->$collection->update($where, $data);

    // $this->db is --> new \MongoClient()->selectDB($db)
}
```

my data is like this:

```
  {
      "_id": "asdasd34234414141",
      "username": "whatever",
      "age": 55,
  }
```

the $newData above is:

```
 ['age'=>20]
```

but what happens after I perform the code is:

```
  {
      "_id": "asdasd34234414141",
      "age": 20
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that $where['id'] is set ? If not, it would mean that you query all the documents, thus applying the modifications on all the documents

Comment: @LouisF. if he finds by _id he will be immune to that problem and since he is using $set this should not be happening

Comment: @LouisF. plus his code is update one only, he is not using multi flag

Comment: What driver version is this? What PHP version?

Comment: Oh I see your problem, you have a typo `$collection = $this->db->$collection->update($where, $data);` should be `$collection = $this->db->$collection->update($where, $newdata);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
$collection = $this->db->$collection->update($where, $data);
```

should be:

```
$collection = $this->db->$collection->update($where, $newdata);
```

The reason you are seeing this is because, by default, MongoDB **will overwrite** the document if no operators are passed. That is standard and documented behaviour.